# RabbitMQ SocketException

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I've installed the RabbitMQ Service on our Windows Server and tried to create a sub/pub demo with c# but I get this exception everytime if I develop the app on another pc other then server where RabbitMQ installed.

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.HostName = "192.168.100.34";
factory.UserName = "username";
factory.Password = "password";

IConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
```

The exception is : *A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied*

I turned off the firewall on server an on pc but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is a first-chance exception as the client may need to retry a few times before successfully opening . You can just <kbd>F5</kbd> past it. It's only showing up because you had break on exception turn on in your options when debugging

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the IP address with the name of the server. I seem to remember something about Kerberos handling host names differently.

This doesn't sound like an Erlang cookie issue, which is the first thing that bit me.

Have you tried pinging the server?

There are pages of troubleshooting advice in the book [RabbitMQ in Action](http://www.manning.com/videla/), currently available as an early-access edition. I'd recommend getting this; it contains many useful tips. Skimming through the troubleshooting section I didn't see anything directly applicable to your issue, though.

Comment: I honestly didn't check the Erlang cookies but actually with the latest versions of RabbitMQ and Erlang, it shouldn't be a problem anymore but I'll take a look at it.

I think it's definitely a network issue and I was thinking maybe it's because the 4 other network adapters on the server that we're using for other things such as iSCSI and Load Balancing.

Server pinging I've already did and all other C# network demos like pure WCF services, TCP clients seem to success when the Firewall is off.

Comment: The Erlang cookie is only relevant when connecting multiple Erlang nodes (for instance, when using rabbitmqctl on a broker node, or when connecting directly with the Erlang client).  It can't have any effect on the .NET client.